# context menu on left mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

the description of [jsTree contextmenu](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/contextmenu) says "The contextmenu plugin enables a contextual menu to be shown, when the user right-clicks a node (**or when triggered programatically** by the developer)."

could somebody tell me how

- I can **trigger** the menu **on left** mouse click
- leave the right mouse as it is

Comment: Please stop writing tags in question titles.

Answer (score 5):

Since JSTree 3

```
$('#jstree_list').jstree({
   ...
}).on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        data.instance.show_contextmenu(data.node)
    }, 100);
});
```

The delay seems necessary, I don't know exactly why

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger context menu on `elem` (eg. a <li>) by `$(elem).trigger('contextmenu.jstree')`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Here's how you do it:

```
element.jstree({
  .
  .
  .
}).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
  setTimeout(function() {data.rslt.obj.children('a').trigger('contextmenu')}, 100);
});
```

Note that the triggering is done in a setTimeout(). It did not work for me otherwise.